# Apply fixed background to images in angular

Tags: angular, image

I am using angular 7 and am complete beginner with this. I am stuck at a point with no understanding of *how* to do this. I was able to have images resized so that either the height is 270 and width is lesser than 470 or width is 470 and height is lesser than 270. I want to save these images after applying them to a white background of 470 width and 270 height while keeping the image in the middle. Conversely, I could apply white padding to the image either for width or height equally on both sides so that the final image is 470 *270. I have searched over the internet and could not find anything. If someone can guide me, I will be very much helped and thankful.

Examples of desired outputs are as below. For better visibility, I have kept the background black instead of white.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got good information on:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-overlay-an-image-over-another-in-node-jimp

you can overlay an image on desired size using composite().

Comment: Please post your solution don't just paste a link.